# How to put PHP script in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that allow users to access it. This page have certain things that not allow `user` to see that particular thing, For my case, user is unable to edit `edit()` or view this function, so I want to hide it by putting below code in JS because I am using function on this link.

I already enabled Session in PHP page like this `<?php session_start(); ?>`

And I try this putting this PHP in JS inside Datatables function. The dataTable function is working fine. Just the PHP is not working.

```
{ data : "project_id",
    render: function(data) {
    return  "<span onclick='view()'></span>&nbsp;"+    // This is allow to user and admin level
            "<?php 
              if ($_SESSION['user_privilege'] == 'Admin') { ?>
                 <span onclick='edit()'</span>
             <?php } ?>";   // This is allow for admin level only
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean the PHP is not working? Please be specific as possible

Comment: it mean user level still can see.view `view()`, should be not. I have two `<span>`.

Comment: maybe you can reply at the answer section, I don't get it

Comment: do a `var_dump($_SESSION);`. What does it give you?

Comment: sorry, typo, user level only can see `view()`, user level should be not to see `edit()`

Comment: In that case, if your users can see the `edit` part, you've admitted the admin rights to your users.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I got `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in......... NULL`

Answer (score 6):

Check the following

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["user_user_privilege"])){
  echo "<script>
     let button = '<span onclick='edit()'></span>';
  </script>";
}else{
 echo "<script>
     let button = '';
  </script>";
}
?>
```

Now check the button is empty or not.

```
{ data : "project_id",
    render: function(data) {
    return  "<span onclick='view()'></span>&nbsp;"+  ((button!="") ? button : "");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I replicate your upper answer in .php file but have red underline at `let button = "<span onclick='edit()'</span>";`

Comment: I have made changes. check it now

Comment: `$_SESSION["user_user_privilege"])` is just like that? or `($_SESSION['user_privilege'] == "Admin")`

Comment: If you want to check $_SESSION["user_user_privilege"] is set or not, so pass the session into isset function.
If you want to check session value so you can use condition like that ($_SESSION['user_privilege'] == "Admin")

Comment: i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: edit is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (home.php:1)
onclick @ home.php:1`

Comment: Have you created edit() function. if not so please create edit() function

Comment: yes already create and the function is working. modal is appear. On yes, the button is unseen.

Comment: May I know what is `((button!="") ? button : "");` use for? inside double quote it is need to put a condition?

Comment: button is variable created in php code.
button value is <span onclick='edit()'></span>, If session exists, then button value is <span onclick='edit()'></span>, if session not exists so button value is empty.

Comment: you upper and bottom solutions is required each other or choose either one? sorry I am new in php

Comment: Upper code is of php, that  is generating the button variable, It checks if session is set then create variable with value of "span" tag, if session is not set, so button value is empty.

Comment: do you have email? maybe I can share the actual issue? just a part yg the code for understanding.. sorry because I cannot relate to my case.

Comment: hassankwl1001@gmail.com, you can send on it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your cooperation and kindness, I just got the answer, and it work successfully. Thanks again.